# Replace key fob with phone

Tags: android, key, galaxy

I'm a very forgetful person. I just got a key fob for my work, and the next day I forget to bring it.

Having a background in computer science(but very little in hardware/electronics) I was curious what the feasibility would be to use my phone to replace the key fob. My boss would be fine with it, if i can get it to work. Does my phone even have the hardware capable of transmitting the information? If it can, would it be possible to read my own personal fob key?

Comment: You can definitely use your phone to unlock door locks if that's what you are getting at. Just do some quick Google searches. I'm sure there is probably an easier way to do it with modern phones via NFC

Comment: How about a bit of double-sided tape to attach your keyfob to your phone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlikely, I would say.

First thing you need to know is the type of your key fob - technology, frequency, protocol? Most EU car/garage key fob is 433.92 MHz, which is no way to be simulated on phone but you can find a duplicator on eBay easily.

If your key fob is NFC or Bluetooth, you may have better chance.

Comment: Id have to ask, but from what ive seen of bluetooth fobs, i dont believe it is. If i had to take a guess its RFID. Sometimes i just need SO to put things into perspective for me, and this has gotten me down the road i need for more research. Marking as answer for that reason alone.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate my fob with my phone but was unsuccessful. Instead, I opened the FOB up and carefully removed the coil and chip.  It was glued in, so a small amount of heat was required (on the fob, not the coil).

Once I got the coil out, I put it in between my phone and the back of my phone case. The downside is that my phone tries to read it occasionally. So, perhaps test your phones sensitivity to the chip prior to attempting this.

Oh, this approach does assume your company does not mind giving you a new fob if you destroy it.